# How to pass a parameter inside javascript call?

Tags: c#, javascript

I tried to call a c# function from JavaScript - I want to pass the parameter along with that method, but how do I pass the parameter?

Below is the javascript in the aspx page:

```
function CallCodeBehind(id) {
    var a = '<%=CallFromJS(--parameter need pass here --)%>';
}
```

The below method is in the code-behind

```
public string CallFromJS(id) {
    int id=id;
    getNames(id);    
    return null;
}
```

And the Button code is:

```
<Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="CallCodeBehind(<%=(id)%>)"     Text="Upload" />
```

Comment: Please, edit your question properly. I suspect some tags are missing in that.

Comment: `CallFromJS` doesn't have any parameter, so how could you pass a parameter to it?

Comment: CallFromJS should return a string but returns null?

Comment: Shall i add like this var a = "<%=CallFromJS('"+ id + "')%>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMethods can have parameters, but method has to be static.

Server side (*.cs code behind) :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Hello(string name)
{
  return "Hello " + name;
}
```

And then call it from javascript like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SayHelloToMe(param) {
      PageMethods.Hello(param, OnSuccess, OnError);
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
      alert(response);
    }

    function OnError(error) {
      alert(error);  
    }  
</script>
```

and button :

```
<Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="SayHelloToMe('<%=(id)%>')"     Text="Upload" />
```

Of course id has to be public, and on that form you have to have ScriptManager with PageMethods enabled, like this :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scMan" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: its codebehind(C#) shall i use webmethod? and also i need pass dynamic parameter.

Comment: Shall i add like this var a = "<%=CallFromJS('"+ id + "')%>";

Comment: i getting this error " Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'PageMethods' is undefined"

Comment: yes i already have script manager <form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="main">

Comment: well I don't know, I tried that code in a empty project and it works OK

Comment: is there any other option call c# function to javascript

Comment: yes there is, for example ASHX, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517379/how-do-you-call-an-ashx-from-javascript or use jQuery http://brijbhushan.net/2011/05/29/call-httphandler-from-jquery-pass-data-and-retrieve-in-json-format/

Comment: why method should be static?? if any reason please tell my method have repeater control

Comment: becouse you don't want instantiate whole page for one method. That is the way WebMethods work. Otherwise use UpdatePanel